# Repeat the same color order using nth-child in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nwf2A/57/

I have a problem with the display of an order of colors using the `nth-child` pseudo-class.

The first set of 4 `div`s display the correct colors in the right order, but I want the second and third sets to display the same order of colors.

Below is my HTML and CSS;

**HTML:**

```
<div> </div><div> </div><div> </div><div> </div>
<br>
<div> </div><div> </div><div> </div><div> </div>
<br>
<div> </div><div> </div><div> </div><div> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {height: 20px;margin: 5px;}
div:nth-child(1n) {background: blue;}
div:nth-child(2n) {background: red;}
div:nth-child(3n) {background: green;}
div:nth-child(4n) {background: black;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following CSS will give you the solution you require.

```
div {height: 20px;margin: 5px;}
div:nth-child(5n+1) {background: blue;}
div:nth-child(5n+2) {background: red;}
div:nth-child(5n+3) {background: green;}
div:nth-child(5n+4) {background: black;}
```

`<br>` is also an element, so you need to select every 5th element (`5n`) with an offset for each color (`+1`, `+2`, etc).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
div {height: 20px;margin: 5px;}
div:nth-of-type(4n) {background: blue;}
div:nth-of-type(4n+1) {background: red;}
div:nth-of-type(4n+2) {background: green;}
div:nth-of-type(4n+3) {background: black;}
```

change the **nth-child** to **nth-of-type**

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yugi47/Nwf2A/59/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 3):

```
div {height: 5px;margin: 5px;}
div:nth-child(5n+1) {background: red;}
div:nth-child(5n+2) {background: blue;}
div:nth-child(5n+3) {background: green;}
div:nth-child(5n+4) {background: black;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The :nth-child() and :nth-of-type() pseudo-classes allows you to select elements with a formula.

```
1 row -> 1n blue
2 row -> 2n red
3 row -> 3n green
4 row -> 4n black
5 row -> empty (br is also an element)
6 row -> 3n green
7 row -> 1n blue
8 row -> 4n black
same logic till the end
```

Because of that the colors are different, try to use correct formula by n.

Edit: @worldofjr wrote you the correct formula for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use like this:-

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwf2A/58/)

```
div:nth-child(5n+1) {background: blue;}
div:nth-child(5n+2) {background: red;}
div:nth-child(5n+3) {background: green;}
div:nth-child(5n+4) {background: black;}
```